# How does light affect saturation?

Tags: color, lighting

Based on my current knowledge, light increases the saturation of a color. If that's the case, then the form shadow of an object should have lower saturation than the part of the object hit by light (not the highlight; just the part of the object that's between the highlight and terminator).

However, after studying both traditional and digital artists' works, I noticed that many people increase the saturation in the shadows and decrease it in the light.

Why do they do that? Are they simply using artistic license because they don't want to lose color in the shadows?

Comment: Have you applied similar studies to photographs and nature? Such as still lifes and the like? Do your observations of natural saturation levels mesh in your head (!) with what you see in analysis of artworks?

Comment: I do not think you are correct in your theory regarding light and saturation. What if the light is a tint that is complementary to the surface color? you will get grey or black instead of more saturation. If a full spectrum light is over powering you will get get washed out colors (think of a desert scene at noon).

Comment: @WebHead I've been refraining from taking photos because I've been told that modern cameras exaggerate the saturation of colors. Instead, I've been creating scenes with models and lighting in Cycles, a path-tracing rendering engine that's supposed to be physically accurate. When I save the rendered image to a file and open it in my painting app, I color-pick the various color zones. Cycles actually shows _no_ change in saturation in the light or the shadows.

Comment: @rebusB Yea, I'm aware of how complementary colors neutralize each other. What had me banging my head against my desk is an environment with normal white light. I think I've got it now. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Look at [Josef Albers "Interaction of Color"](http://www.g-e-s-t-a-l-t.org/MEDIA/PDF/Interaction-of-Color.pdf). There is a lot more to experiencing color than a pixel RGB value interpreted as HSV. The choice of color for a shadow is as much about the colors around it as the color in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's take a look at a photo of a colored object.
This is a simple, bright blue 20-sided die. I picked this because the shape and lighting make it easy to see multiple levels of brightness.
[image]

I then took this image and imported it into Adobe Color Wheel, which has quickly become one of my favorite tools for analyzing palettes when I don't have access to an art program. I find digital tools are a great supplement for learning traditional art skills, especially when you're teaching yourself.

[image]

Let's look at the immediate observations:

- The hues all "line" up, which we should expect. It's a single-color object (excluding the text), and the lighting is clear and white, so there's no hue shifting
- The tool captured the range of brightness levels, so we should be OK using this as an example

In this case, looking at the actually HSB number, we can see the shadow is actually slightly less saturated than the midtones, but the caveat here is that it's based on the pixel selected for that color. Picking different pixels from the "15" side in the shadow yield slight differences in saturation, and mainly it's on-par with the midtones.

But, as you've observed in artworks, the highlighted sides (17, 18), have decreased in saturation. Why is that?

Let's talk about light!

The way that light and objects interact is inverted from what we actually see. So a bright blue object like this, which is almost *completely* blue, actually *reflects* Blue light back to our eyes. **The object itself is absorbing Red and Green light (when basing this on the RGB color scale, which is what visible light is based on)**.

When you shine white light onto an object, you're essentially shining all colors onto that object (the die, here). The shadows, receiving less light, will still absorb the Red and Green light, reflecting back lower *amounts* of Blue light. Because the amount of light is reduced, the *brightness* value on the HSB (Hue/Saturation/Brightness) scale with be lower, but the Hue and Saturation stay essentially the same.

**But as you increase the amount, or intensity, of the white light being cast on the die, you reach a point where the physical properties of the object can't absorb as much Red and Green light**, so it starts reflecting some of that, as well. When the light is strong enough, or a point reflective enough, it may even appear to us as pure white, which is a color with no saturation (like pure black or grey).

Since the light being reflected back is no longer pure Blue, the saturation decreases. This is because saturation (colorfulness, chroma, intensity, etc) is measured by the difference in the levels of color from gray, or in other words the difference in the dominant hue(s) from the remaining hue(s).

This also explains why shadows of a form still often maintain the same level of saturation: the die has no problem absorbing the meager amount of Red and Green being cast on it. Although, in this case, the object does absorb *some* Blue, so at low enough levels, we might see the saturation decrease, because proportion of reflected Blue light is lower.

Note that all this is mostly the theoretical application of light as it would apply to art. Rarely is a subject going to be lit from a single, clear, diffuse white light. Most environments are going to have multiple light sources, often not pure, and you'll be dealing with reflection of colored light off nearby objects. That's when the artistic eye and choices really come into play.

Comment: Fantastic explanation. I've been studying light and color for a while, but my question was something I  just _couldn't_ find answers for. When you wrote "But as you increase the amount, or intensity, of the white light being cast on the dice, you reach a point where the physical properties of the object can't absorb as much Red and Green light," you hit the nail on the head for my question, because I didn't know that little tidbit. Now everything makes more sense.Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @MeshHead Glad it helped. Thankfully, I remember some stuff from my physics class, lol.

Comment: Thank you so much!! this cleared up a lot of things for me <3